# Accept multiple IntellijIdea's inspection suggestions at the same time (all of the same type)

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, assert, validation

I made a mistake and I flipped expected and actual in my assert assertEqual.

Fortunately after importing project IntellijIdea detected problem and suggested flipping arguments.

Unfortunately this problem is repeated in multiple assertEquals.

Is it possible to accept multiple IntellijIdea's inspection suggestions at the same time? I found only way to accept it for a single instance of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and select [*Run Inspection by Name*](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/running-inspection-by-name.html) (or hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>), select the inspection you want to run, select the scope (current file, whole project ...) and hit Enter.

All candidates for the inspection you selected will be shown in a tool window. You can then select the ones you want to apply the inspection to, right click and choose what to do from the menu (for instance Delete if the inspection is unused declaration).